# AWS- Does modyfing lambda update the CloudFormation Stack instantly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Lets say I have a CloudFormation stack running, which creates and deploys an Lambda function. In the AWS Console, if I connect my Lambda function to an API in API Gateway, will my CloudFormation Template be updated immediately if the Lambda function successfully integrates with the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a one way traffic from Cloudformation to resources.

Meaning if you modify your Cloudformation template and update the stack then the resources that were created by Cloudformation get modified/updated. However the other way is not true. Meaning if you modify your resources the Cloudformation template does not get updated.

Moreover, as a good practice you should avoid modifying the resources directly because you may end up breaking the Cloudformation's update stack functionality for that that stack